# Python seems to automatically convert a list to a string, after which .append() and .pop() are unusable

Tags: python, string, list

I'm using Python 3.6 and PyCharm if that matters at all. I'm also fairly new to Python programming (especially working with files) so sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

I am trying to make a script that writes the first 20 items from the [look-and-say sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence) into a file, each item on a separate line. The script works fine for the first 4 lines, however, raises an exception afterwards.

```
LINES = 20
with open("sequence.txt", "r+") as finalOutput:
    finalOutput.truncate(0)
    finalOutput.write("1")
    for i in range(LINES-1):
        finalOutput.seek(0)
        prevLine = finalOutput.readlines()[-1]
        newLine = ""
        block = []
        for c in prevLine:
            if c == "\n":
                break
            else:
                block.append(c)
                if block[-1] != block[0]:
                    newLine += str(len(block[:-1]))
                    newLine += str(block[0])
                    block = block.pop()
        if len(block) != 0:
            newLine += str(len(block))
            newLine += str(block[0])
        finalOutput.write("\n" + newLine)
```

After "1211" is written into the file, I'm presented with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ViAik/PycharmProjects/1_11_21_1211_sequence/main.py", line 
14, in <module>
    block.append(c)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Which implies that `block` is a string, even though it started out as a list (?). What confuses me the most is that the first 4 lines work properly.

I am not even sure how to formulate my actual question here because I don't understand what's actually going on. I suppose that figuring that out is my question, and hopefully I can fix this code in a way that doesn't involve purposefully using `block` as a string. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`block = block.pop()`

This makes block become it's own last element, which is a string. I'm not sure what you expect to happen here.

e.g.

```
block = ['hello', 'world']
block = block.pop()
print(block)  # --> world
```

Comment: Thanks, changing it to `block = [block.pop()]` fixed the problem. Stupid mistake that I didn't recognize after half an hour of looking at the code and trying to fix it...

Comment: It's probably more efficient (and more obvious) if you just write `block = block[-1:]`

Answer (score 0):

Python works on the concept of reference object.
Variable names are references to the actual object. When a name is on the right hand side of an equation, the object that it references is automatically looked up and used in the equation.
So when you write:

```
 block = [] # the name block is a reference to a list
```

But when you again reference name block to a new object, it will point to the last reference object it assign.

```
block = block.pop() # the name block is a reference to string object.
```

So when you try to append an element in *block* it gives you error.